# Why the methods returning many value instead of one in each array?

Tags: java, methods

I have a problem in returning type in Java. 
The program is about decomposing an integer of 5 chiffres to an array without using predefined methods just with classic algorithm in a recursive way.
I wrote the code and it work well with recursion, 
but when I catch the new array from the method it doesn't return a single value in each case but it returns two to 5 chiffres in one single case.
What I want to achieve is this:

> 12345 >> [1][2][3][4][5]

but my algorithm gave me this:

> 12345 >> [0][12][123][1234][12345]

I guess that the problem is in the returning type or in declaring method.

This is the my Code:

```
public class recursive {

  static int[] Decompose (int[] tab , int pos,int num) //pos for position
  {
    if (pos == 0) //if it reach the last element of the table it stop
    {
      return tab;
    } 
    else {
      tab[pos]=num;
      return Decompose(tab,pos-1,num/10); // if we didn't reach the end continue ...    
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int []t = new int[5];

    int n=12345;//the number that i want to decompose
    int pos=4;//the indicator of table position

    t=Decompose(t,pos,n);

    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(t[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to store a single digit number in each position of the array, so you should use `%` operator to obtain the last digit:

```
...
tab[pos]=num%10;
return Decompose(tab,pos-1,num/10);
...
```

Comment: and that by adding th "%"

Comment: and by changing the stop condition to -1 instead of 0 like this
{
 static int[] Decompose (int[] tab , int pos,int num) //pos for position
 {
 if (pos <= -1) //if it reach the last element of the table it stop
 {
  return tab;
 } 
 else {
tab[pos]=num%10;
return Decompose(tab,pos-1,num/10); // if we didn't reach the end continue ...}

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the array to the actual number each time, that's why you're getting the whole number minus one in each iteration. You should change the tab assignment to:

```
tab[pos] = num % 10;
```

Also the position should reach the index 0, so change the check to:

```
if (pos < 0)
```